# How to redirect console output to file and STILL get it in the console?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, unix

I want to run an ANT script which prompts the user for input, so it needs to be interactive through the console. at the same time I want to log the console content to a log file.
I know I can use `ant >build.log 2<&1` which will redirect to file, but leave the console empty.

So, how can that be done? needed on windows and unix.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `tee`.

```
ant 2>&1|tee build.log
```

tee.exe is also available for Windows from http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Bewarned that piping to tee will hide any errors from the ant script (i.e. in ERRORLEVEL)

Comment: Be sure to use tee -a for appending it to file. I accidentally overwritten old logs because of this.

Comment: That link does not contain tee as of 2023.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `tee`.

Example:

```
$ echo "Hello, world" | tee /tmp/outfile
Hello, world
$ cat /tmp/outfile
Hello, world
```

`tee` writes its stdin to both stdout as well as one or more files given on the command line.