# How to redirect console input to file bash

Tags: bash, redirect, input, console

I have a console application whose output I want to appear on the console and stored in a file.  I have been using tee to output to console and to a file, but I also want the user input to get written to the file

Write now I have been using

./a.out | tee -a output.txt

I have seen a lot of suggestions for how to redirect from a file and also saw this link [How to redirect console output to file and STILL get it in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612608/how-to-redirect-console-output-to-file-and-still-get-it-in-the-console)

which suggested using 2>$1, but that still doesn't get the user input into the file.

Comment: ` nano some_file` :)

Comment: You'll need to `echo` the user input in the program itself to get it into the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `script` command.

e.g. `script inout.txt ./a.out`